# using curl in php to publish data with faye

Tags: php, node.js, faye

According to the author of faye i can send messages from any platform
and the format to post a message with curl is:

```
curl -X POST http://192.168.1.101:8000/faye -H 'Content-Type:
    application/json' -d '{"channel":"/foo","data":{"hello":"world"}}'
```

I format the previous line to be used in php

```
$data = array("channel" => "/one", "result" => "Hello World from PHP!!");  
$data_string=json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('http://192.168.1.101:8000/faye');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string);                                                          
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);                                                              
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(
'Content-Type:application/json','Content-Length:'strlen($data_string)));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Somehow the subscriber to channel one DOES not GET the result

the publish function in java script works seamlessly (see line below)

```
var publication = client.publish('/one',{ result: 'Hello World from JS'});<br/>
```

Please let me know what is missing or my mistake thanks

Comment: Shouldn't "result" be "data"?

Comment: I made a mistake adjusting the publish function to curl.   
the Correct value for $data_string should be:
1) $data_string = '{"channel":"/one","data":{"result":"Hello World from PHP!!"}}';
OR
2) $data = array("channel" => "/one", "data" => array  ("result"=>"HelloWorld from PHP!!"));  
 $data_string = json_encode($data);  thanks!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @edino: If you have solved the problem yourself, you should write the solution as a reply and accept the answer. That will mark the question as answered and stop people (like me) spending time understanding your problem only to find you have solved it already in the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me:

```
$data = array("channel" => "/one", "data" => array ("result"=>"HelloWorld from PHP!!"));
$data_string=json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost:8000/faye');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string);                                                          
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);                                                              
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type:application/json'));
echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
```